# Swisscom App Cloud: CF Push hangs/won't finish

Tags: deployment, cloud-foundry, bamboo, swisscomdev

Since today I have the problem that the CF push task in bamboo will hang on the `Uploading app files` step. I didn't change anything besides some environment variables and of course a bit of code. The log looks like this:

> Creating/updating app App-X...
>
> Uploading App-X... Uploading app files
>
> from: /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/App-X-JOB1/

This will run forever without the Application Cloud getting any updates.
Are there any good ways to debug CF push tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to debug your deployment as close as possible to the way you execute it on bamboo. If you do a `cf push`, the cf cli automatically tails the staging logs for you, so if you don't see any output during staging it's unlikely that `cf logs` will tell you anything more.

Since the last thing you're seeing from the log snippet posted above is an "uploading" statement, I would check these things:

- use a more recent version of the cf cli, they recently added an upload progress bar which might be useful
- check if you have either a `.gitignore` or `.cfignore` file in the dir you're pushing from so that you don't push any files you don't need ([docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#exclude))
- hanging pushes may be a plain malfunction of the CF platform you're using, e.g. due to inavailability of CFs internal blob store, no more cells available for staging etc., there's tons of possibilites here

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder at [Meshcloud](https://www.meshcloud.io/en/home-2/) and we provide public and private (also on-site/hybrid) managed Cloud Foundry hosting in the EU.

Comment: What exactly do you disclaim? Seems like hidden ad

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full trace log of a push by using `cf push -v`, which might give you a hint of where (and possibly why) it is stuck.

Other useful debugging tools are `cf logs` / `cf logs --recent` and `cf events`, but if the push itself simply hangs (rather than failing), they might not produce anything at all. Have you tried waiting for the timeout?

Also, please make sure you're using the latest cf cli version.

Comment: Also double check that `-p` or `path` is set correctly & that you don't have more than you expect in the path.  You can run `du -h -d 1 <path>` to list the size of folders in your path or use Windows Explorer to check.  Sometimes cf will hang at the point you're seeing cause it's trying to push a huge mess of files.

Comment: Ok I will try that. I totally forgot to mention that I'm using bamboo, that might change things, right?